# How to check the uniqueness of lists inside list?

Tags: python, list

I have this data:

```
[[prodcutname,price_rate,price,quantity]]

[['phone', '500', 450.0, 1], ['phone', '500', 2250.0, 5], ['camera', '200', 1080.0, 6], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1],['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1]]
```

Now, what I need to do is create a new list with only unique elements(products), and add other values of the same product and put them into list.
The ideal output would look like:

```
[['phone','500',2700,6],['camera','220',1080,6],....]
```

I tried doing this using -

```
unique_list = ['phone', '500', 450.0, 1]

big_list = []
mylist = []

for i in range(len(larger_list)):
    for j in range(1,len(larger_list)):
        if(larger_list[i][0]==larger_list[j][0]):
            # Getting the sum or prices and number
            #Sum of price
            larger_list[j][2]=larger_list[i][2]+larger_list[j][2]

            #Sum of number
            larger_list[j][3]=larger_list[i][3]+larger_list[j][3]

            #Adding into a new list
            unique_list[0]=larger_list[i][0]
            unique_list[1]=larger_list[i][1]
            unique_list[2]=larger_list[j][2]
            unique_list[3]=larger_list[j][3]

            mylist.append(unique_list)
            big_list.append(mylist)
            mylist = []

return big_list
```

But ran into a lot of error to no avail. I even tried by putting them into dictionary. How do I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: please show what is your desired output, 'unique' in this case could mean many things... do you want to remove all items with the same product name? if so what do you do with the rest of the items with that name?

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Yes. My desired output is to remve same product name and add other attributes.

Comment: What happens with the second value? It's not added for `phone`, and the value for `camera` is different than the one in the list.

Answer (score 3):

A Dictionary in Python means fairly the same thing as the word `Dictionary`. This implies, You can so easily lookup the `Value` of any `keyword` using the Keyword directly. This is, unfortunately, not possible with a `list` since lists are `numerically` indexed. It is thus recommended to first Convert your list into a Dictionary for 2 reasons: 
*1: Easier Mapping of the given Data to `Individual` Keys.* 
*2: Processing the Data-Values to obtain your desired result.*
As the Result of the `Print` shows, it is now easier to access any data by using the Key (even within a loop). For example, `to get the Price of Phones`, You can simply do: 
`dictList['phone']['price']` which is much more easier than doing something like: `flatList[0][2]` which is really not so intuitive....

```
product_list    = [
    ['phone',  '500', 450.0,  1],
    ['phone',  '500', 2250.0, 5],
    ['camera', '200', 1080.0, 6],
    ['laptop', '600', 540.0,  1],
    ['laptop', '600', 540.0,  1],
    ['laptop', '600', 540.0,  1]
]

# CREATE A LIST OF DICTIONARY FROM GIVEN DATA FOR EASIER MAPPING
item        = ["product_name", "price_rate", "price", "quantity"]
dictList    = {}
for data in product_list:
    if data[0] not in dictList:
        dictList[data[0]]   = dict(zip(item, data))
    else:
        tmpD    = dict(zip(item, data))
        dictList[data[0]]["price"]      = float(dictList[data[0]]["price"]) + float(tmpD['price'])
        dictList[data[0]]["quantity"]   = float(dictList[data[0]]["quantity"]) + float(tmpD['quantity'])
        # dictList[data[0]]["price_rate"] = float(dictList[data[0]]["price_rate"]) + float(tmpD['price_rate'])

print(dictList)
## PRINTS:
## {
##  'phone':  {'product_name': 'phone',  'price_rate': '500', 'price': 2700.0, 'quantity': 6.0}, 
##  'camera': {'product_name': 'camera', 'price_rate': '200', 'price': 1080.0, 'quantity': 6}, 
##  'laptop': {'product_name': 'laptop', 'price_rate': '600', 'price': 1620.0, 'quantity': 3.0}
## }
```

However, if for any reason you need to have your Data as a List, it is also quite easier with a simple `list composition` like so:

```
item        = ["product_name", "price_rate", "price", "quantity"]
dictList    = {}
for data in product_list:
    if data[0] not in dictList:
        dictList[data[0]]   = dict(zip(item, data))
    else:
        tmpD    = dict(zip(item, data))
        dictList[data[0]]["price"]      = float(dictList[data[0]]["price"]) + float(tmpD['price'])
        dictList[data[0]]["quantity"]   = float(dictList[data[0]]["quantity"]) + float(tmpD['quantity'])
        # dictList[data[0]]["price_rate"] = float(dictList[data[0]]["price_rate"]) + float(tmpD['price_rate'])

arrayList   = [ list(dVal.values()) for dKey, dVal in dictList.items() ]
print(arrayList)
## PRINTS:
## [
##     ['phone',  '500', 2700.0, 6.0], 
##     ['camera', '200', 1080.0, 6], 
##     ['laptop', '600', 1620.0, 3.0]
## ]
```

Comment: If you could explain why using dictionary (in term of complexity) is better than using lists then your answer will be great -- because now it only assumes that's what OP needs, but he might need to only return a list.

Comment: @OwlMax  Thanks for the Feedback. Will update the Answer to take that into consideration....

Comment: @Poiz Thank you for the answer. I don't necessarily need the data to be in list, dictionary can do the job too and I can output the data from previous function with dictionary too. Your answer did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` in Python3:

```
import itertools
s = [['phone', '500', 450.0, 1], ['phone', '500', 2250.0, 5], ['camera', '200', 1080.0, 6], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1],['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1]]
new_s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_s = [[a, b[0][1], *list(map(sum, list(zip(*[i[2:] for i in b]))))] for a, b in new_s]
```

Output:

```
[['camera', '200', 1080.0, 6], ['laptop', '600', 1620.0, 3], ['phone', '500', 2700.0, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can build a `dict` :

```
>>> l
[['camera', '200', 1080.0, 6], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1], ['laptop', '600', 540.0, 1], ['phone', '500', 450.0, 1], ['phone', '500', 2250.0, 5]]
>>> for i in l:
...     if i[0] in d:
...             d[i[0]].append(i[1:])
...     else:
...             d[i[0]]=[i[1:]]
... 
>>> d
{'phone': [['500', 450.0, 1], ['500', 2250.0, 5]], 'laptop': [['600', 540.0, 1], ['600', 540.0, 1], ['600', 540.0, 1]], 'camera': [['200', 1080.0, 6]]}
```